# FreeIPA re-arrange custom attributes

Tags: ldap, freeipa

I created several custom attributes and added them to LDAP and FreeIPA, but their order in the user page is very messy.

I want to re-arrange them and put the related attributes together (such as 'initiation date' should be followed by 'termination date')

How can I do that??

Answer (score 2):

OK I found the solution and it's very simple.

The new attributes are displayed in the order by which their JavaScript plugins are added into the server.